# Pre-loaded sounds being unloaded?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, preload

So, I have the following test code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
   <button onclick="play()">Play</button>
    <script>
        var sounds = new Array();
        preloadSnd = function(){
            var snds = new Array();
            for(i = 0; i < preloadSnd.arguments.length; i++){
                snds[i] = new Audio();
                snds[i].src = preloadSnd.arguments[i];
            }
            sounds.push(snds);
        }
        preloadSnd(
            "test1.mp3",
            "test2.mp3",
            "test3.mp3",
            "test4.mp3",
            "test5.mp3",
            "test6.mp3",
            "test7.mp3",
            "test8.mp3"
        )
        play = function(){
            sounds[0][parseInt(Math.random()*8)].play();
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

It pre-loads some audio files and on the click of a button, randomly plays one of them. The problem is, after about a minute or so, some of the audio files seem to get unloaded because they are fetched from the server again when played. This means that once my "application" has loaded, I still need to be connected to the internet to hear some of the sounds. If my cache is enabled it doesn't require connecting to the internet, but I cannot rely on the cache being enabled. Is there any way I can keep these files loaded so that they don't need to be fetched repeatedly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch all your medias as Blobs, and then create blobURIs from it.

This way, the browser will keep it in memory (until an hard refresh or until you call `URL.revokeObjectURL(blobURI);`)

```js
fetch("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/8c9m92u1euqnkaz/GershwinWhiteman-RhapsodyInBluePart1.mp3")
.then(r => r.blob()) // could be xhr.responseType = 'blob'
.then(blob => {
  const aud = new Audio(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
  aud.controls = true;
  document.body.appendChild(aud);
  console.log('Fully loaded and cached until the page dies...')
  });
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot, that totally works. Do you know if there is some way to fall back nicely for older browsers that don't support blob? and also is there some way I can refer to the blobs by a nice name rather than what createObjectURL gives me or am I stuck with just storing the URLs somewhere?

Comment: @SchoolBoy to set up a fallback, `if(!('Blob' in window))fallback()`. What to set in this fallback... I'm not sure. It would target only browsers released between IE9 and IE10 anyway, do you really have such an audience ? (the code in answer is written using the quite new `fetch` API, but as commented, you can also use `XMLHttpRequest.responseType = 'blob'`. For the blobURIs, no, there isn't really a way to set it yourself, but these only lives for the session time, so I'm not sure why you need to *prettify* it. An other alternative would be ServiceWorkers, but that's an other beast.

Comment: Unfortunately yes, my audience may conceivably be using old browsers from the time of IE8. Although that isn't so much of a problem, it would just have been nice. Same with the prettifying. Service workers would just make the problem worse so.. no. :p Thanks for your help!

Comment: IE8 is not evwn in the range of possible to fallback since it didn't support the HTMLAudioElement.

Comment: Yes, I am aware. I have a flash fallback for IE8 and such, so I can trigger that in those cases.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Service Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API).

**OLD ANSWER:**

Otherwise, did you take a look at [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)?

Also, check out [this blog post](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/02/saving-images-and-files-in-localstorage/) about how to store binary data in localStorage.

Comment: Local storage would be fine if it didn't have the size limitation. My applications sounds will not all fit in local storage. And besides, I don't need to store the sounds across sessions, I just want them to load when I load the page and stay loaded till the user navigates away, rather than loading again every time the sound is played.

Comment: Ok, that sounds clear. I updated the answer, maybe service workers can help you.

Comment: Unfortunately that's no good either, I need it to be compatible with Safari and Mobile and service worker support seems fairly slim. It also seems like a very complicated solution for a simple problem. Isn't there any easier way to pre-load audio in javascript?

Comment: True, it's kind of bleeding edge right now. Sorry, I don't think I can help you any further.